# Html Agility Pack link and img src extraction

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I have pages that use images as links, and I am trying to get the href link as well as the images src. The problem is what I have now is collecting the href's fine, but it is only getting the first img src and just repeating.

```
HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(url);
HtmlNodeCollection linkNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");
foreach (HtmlNode linkNode in linkNodes)
{
HtmlAttribute link = linkNode.Attributes["href"];
HtmlNode imageNode = linkNode.SelectSingleNode("//img");
HtmlAttribute src = imageNode.Attributes["src"];

string imageLink = link.Value;
string imageUrl = src.Value;
}
```

Can some one tell me whats wrong or another way of doing it? Thanks.

Comment: The code you posted looks fine to me... Where do you store the extracted image links and urls? In lists? That part of the code is missing. Here you are just declaring the two strings inside the loop scope and therefore discarding them afterwards. I guess that is just for simplifying the code, but the mistake could lie in that part of the code you left out here...

Comment: At the moment to get everything working right I am just printing it in a text box from inside the foreach: output.Text += imageLink + " - " + imageUrl + "\r\n";

Comment: What does the HTML data look like?  What does the contents of the textbox look like?  The code looks fine but we can't possibly understand your situation until we know what you're getting back.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

```
HtmlNode imageNode = linkNode.SelectSingleNode("//img");
```

to

```
HtmlNode imageNode = linkNode.SelectSingleNode(".//img");
```

Hope this helps.